# Play H264/AAC in .NET windows forms application

Tags: .net, ms-media-foundation

I have an app that receives H264 NAL units and AAC packets from a hardware encoder. I would like to show a preview of the stream in the application.

Media Foundation declares that it supports the H264 and AAC codecs, but I have no idea how to go about doing this in .NET.

The alternative might be to embed a Flash player, create a pseudo web server in the app that delivers H264 content wrapped in an FLV file via HTTP.

I would prefer the native windows route using Media Foundation, I've tried looking at Media Foundation .NET, but this project appears discontinued and has little to no documentation.

Does anyone have advice on how to achieve this?